# Trouble making animating boxes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, jquery-animate

Im trying to make 2 animated boxes in jQuery, CSS and HTML, but the code doesn't work. I made the app in a jQuery tutorial app and it runs fine on the app. When I use the exact code on my PC it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

Heres my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing Stuff</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="blueBox"></div>
<div class="redBox"></div>
<style>
.blueBox, .redBox {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
.redBox {
    left: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
.blueBox {
    left: 140px;
    background-color: blue; 
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $blueBox = $('div.blueBox');
    var $redBox = $('div.redBox');
    $blueBox.animate({left: "500px"}, 2000, function(){alert("Animation Completed!");
    });
    $redBox.animate({width: "0px", height: "0px", opacity: "0"}, 3000);

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping me out!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need link the jQuery code in your HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is better you do it in  tag.

If you want [above v1.11.1](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/), get the code link directly from the version through the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/). For exemple:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Do I have to link it to a webpage, or can I link it to a document with that code?

Comment: You need link the jQuery code for every HTML document that uses it.

Comment: Try change the variable names from "$blueBox" and "$redBox" to "blueBox" and "redBox". This works here.